# Git Sparse checkout during Azure pipelines taking ~15 minutes

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, git-sparse-checkout

We have a single repo of our source code which if downloaded is around 2.8GB. We have 4 self hosted agents and over 100 build pipelines. With that, it is not feasible to download the entire source coded for each build/agent.

The approach I gone with is to disable the checkout for these pipeline and then run a command-line script to perform a Git sparse checkout. However this is taking around 15 minutes to get ~100MB worth of source code.

We are using self-hosted Linux agents.

```yaml
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: "Project Specific Checkout"
            inputs:
              script: |
                cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
                git init

                git config --global user.email ""
                git config --global user.name ""
                git config --global core.sparsecheckout true

                echo STARS/Source/A/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
                echo STARS/Source/B/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
                echo STARS/Source/C/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

                git remote rm origin
                git remote add origin https://service:$(Service.Account.Personal.Access.Token)@dev.azure.com/Organization/Project/_git/STARS
                git reset --hard
                git pull origin $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here which is causing it to take so long to pull this data.

Comment: Does it matter that this runs in an Azure pipeline?

Comment: I'm not sure, it may do. I would rather describe my situation in too much detail than too little, otherwise I may be presented with solutions that may not work within my current situation.

Comment: `git pull` may cost much time if the new data is large.

Comment: That's not a good approach. Try to reduce the scope as much as possible to find the cause of the problem. See also [mcve].

Comment: Seems that I'm having a similar issue trying to do it locally on WSL agent. Might it be because it's running PS shell, maybe bash would be faster?

Answer (score -2):

1.Since you use self-hosted agent, you could go to the agent machine, to run the git commands manually, to see whether you would get the same performance.

2.Set variable `system.debug` to `true`, to check which command cost more time.

3.Instead of Git Sparse checkout, you may specify `path` in `checkout` step:

```
steps:
- checkout: self | none | repository name # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found
  clean: boolean  # if true, run `execute git clean -ffdx && git reset --hard HEAD` before fetching
  fetchDepth: number  # the depth of commits to ask Git to fetch; defaults to no limit
  lfs: boolean  # whether to download Git-LFS files; defaults to false
  submodules: true | recursive  # set to 'true' for a single level of submodules or 'recursive' to get submodules of submodules; defaults to not checking out submodules
  path: string  # path to check out source code, relative to the agent's build directory (e.g. \_work\1); defaults to a directory called `s`
  persistCredentials: boolean  # if 'true', leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch; defaults to false
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout

4.Since you run a pipeline on a self-hosted agent, by default, none of the subdirectories are cleaned in between two consecutive runs. As a result, you can do incremental builds and deployments, provided that tasks are implemented to make use of that. So you can set **Clean** option to **false**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: sparse checkout is not same as path. When you specify path, it just checks-out in that path instead of default path 's'. It still checks-out everything in the repo.